# WearOs Watch Face Format: either gps or custom SourceType?

Tags: wear-os, watch-face-api, watchface

What I'm wanting to do is make a Watch Face Format watch face that shows the sun position and moon position and phase, and rise and set times. The moon phase is fortunately included in the [SourceType](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/wff/common/attributes/source-type)s.

Unfortunately sun and moon altitude angle is not included. What I'd like to do is either: access GPS so I can calculate the solar/moon angles or access some Kotlin code as a data source that can make the calculations.

Or at least have an option in the watch face settings to set the location value from GPS.

Obviously I understand I'd want to be sparing with GPS, and sun and moon calcs to save battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So coming back to this the answer is no, but actually yes in a limited sense. The XML doesn't allow any data input, except complications and predefined inputs such as steps and moon phase.

Basically you can make a complication as data channel. You only get 8 complications per watch face so you have to be sparing. The complication has to be in a separate app. The XML doesn't support text to number conversion so all numbers have to be sent in through a RangedValue as either a min, max or value.

In the above question I managed to make a complication that calculates sun rise, set and position. Then uses some math slight of hand to sneak them into the watch face.